# AD Groups VS AD Field for Azure AD User Classification (Pros & Cons of each and Both)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am co-leading a proposal for a mapping of our Azure AD to an external IAM for sync data and we are in the brainstorming part where we need to add some new schemes for mapping new data for the synchronization.

We are inclined to go for a Dynamic Group setting for any new data that the sync will be making but we want to make sure we can justify and my task will be to understand:

- Why we should & shouldn't consider Azure AD Group for user classification?
- Why we should & shouldn't consider Azure AD Field for user classification?
- Why we should & shouldn't consider BOTH for user classification?

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure) for immediate help. Thanks!